# Asymptotic Behavior with continuity and sum

Tags: number-theory

> Show that if $f(x)$ tends to zero monotonically as $x$ increases without limit and is continuous for $x>0$ and if $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1} ^{\infty} f(k)$ diverges then $ \displaystyle \sum_{k=1} ^{n} f(k) \sim \int _1 ^n f(x) dx$.

(We write $f(x) \sim g(x)$ if $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)} < M$).

This is a problem in Leveque's Number Theory that I am stuck on. In the section corresponding to this problem, there is a theorem discussed that mentions $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \log n + \gamma + O(1/n)$ , where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. I am not sure if this would help conclude the problem. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Part of the problem statement got chopped. I will add it here.
If $g(x)$ is a second function satisfying the same hypotheses as $f(x)$ and if $g(x) = o(f(x))$ show that $\sum_{k=1}^n g(k) = o \left( \sum_{k=1}^n f(k) \right)$

(We write $f(x) = o(g(x))$ if $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$).

Comment: Which of Leveque’s books are you referring to? I don’t have a copy on hand and I’m sure that quite a few people on this site don’t either so if you can post the theorem and proof for the harmonic sum relation from that book then that may be helpful. There’s a good chance that the technique used to prove that theorem will generalize to a proof for the exercise here since that theorem is a special case of the exercise. It is late where I’m at and so this is all I can say for now.

Comment: Fundamentals of Number Theory is the book. The theorem is the equality I put in the question. The proof is quite involved and has pictures, should I still post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality we may assume that $f(x)\ge 0$ on $(1,\infty )$.

Note that in that case $f(x)$ is decreasing on $ (1,\infty)$ and   $$ f(2)+f(3)+...+ f(n) \le \int _1 ^n f(x) dx \le f(1)+f(2) + f(3) +...+f(n-1)$$

As $n\to \infty $ we get $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=2} ^{\infty} f(k)\le \int _1 ^{\infty} f(x) dx \le\displaystyle \sum_{k=1} ^{\infty} f(k)$$

Thus the infinite sum and the integral have the same behaviour.

Comment: My trouble was not seeing that $f$ was decreasing to get that inequality. The problem missed a part which I added in, could you look into that? Is it enough to say that it follows from the inequality just proved?

Comment: Yes, it is enough to refer to the theorem say that it follows from the inequality.